# Determine the propositional form and truth value of the following

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

In "A Transition to Advanced Mathematics", the 8th edition, problem (7e), I must determine the propositional form and truth value for the following:

> Although $51$ divides $153$, it is neither prime nor a divisor of $409$

### Attempt

Here is my attempt:

If $P=\text{51 divides 153}$, $Q=\text{51 is prime}$, and $R=\text{51 is a divisor of 409}$, then the propositional statement can be described as the following:

$$P\land\sim(Q\lor R)$$

Also; since $P$ is true, $Q$ is false, and $R$ is false; the propositional statement has the following truth value:

\begin{align}
& T\land\sim(F\lor F)\\
& T\land \sim F \\
& T\land T \\
& T
\end{align}

Therefore the truth value of the propositional statement is true.

**Question:** Am I correct?

Book Details :
["A Transition to Advanced Mathematics 7th ED"](https://www.amazon.in/Transition-Advanced-Mathematics-Douglas-Smith/dp/0495562025)
["A Transition to Advanced Mathematics 8th ED"](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/1285463269)

Authors :: Douglas Smith & Maurice Eggen & Richard St Andre

Comment: It is Correct , though I think the given Statement is actually [[ $ P \land ( \sim Q \land \sim R ) $ ]] which then gets Directly Converted to what you gave !

Comment: 1. I think you've satisfied what the exercise wants, but the exercise is a little artificial, because why use 'although' when there is no clear contrasting, and I wonder whether the sentence "although cats are dogs, they are animals" is false or illegit; my point is that although the word 'although' has logical meaning 'and', propositional logic does fully capture its meaning/nuances. $\quad$ 2. @Prem The OP's suggestion, rather than yours, is arguably the more direct translation! $\quad$

Comment: My Answer is Essentially a response to your Comment , @ryang , I have a little more to add to it , maybe by tomorrow !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially Correct , & your Conclusion is Valid.

There are a few finer Points to high-light , which will aid in the more general Case.

### (1) Neither Nor :

There are 2 ways to convert "neither X nor Y" :
(1A) "not X AND not Y" ...
(1B) ... which is Equivalent to "not (X OR Y)" by the Laws of DeMorgan.

Here (1A) is Direct , Easy & Smooth , not requiring Brackets , unlike (1B) which requires a way to negate a Bracket , which is generally unusual in Natural Languages.

OP Statement given is thus $ P \land (∼Q \land ∼R) $ , which is Equivalent to $ P \land ∼ (Q \lor R) $ , by the Laws of DeMorgan.

**Supporting the (1A) View :**

[https://www.csm.ornl.gov/~sheldon/ds/ex1.1.2.html](https://www.csm.ornl.gov/%7Esheldon/ds/ex1.1.2.html) :

> ... the phrase **"neither A nor B"** is translated as **"not A and not B"**.  Additionally ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201034/translating-neither-nor-into-a-mathematical-logical-expression , Accepted Answer :

> **"Neither P nor Q"** can be rephrased as **"It is not the case that P, and it is not the case that Q"**

https://www.cs.miami.edu/home/geoff/Courses/TPTPSYS/Practicum/EnglishToLogic.shtml , Point 6 :

> Neither, nor. **"Neither p nor q"** means that **both p and q are false**. Therefore translate it **~p & ~q** or ~(p | q). These two formulas are equivalent by DeMorgan's Theorem.

There are more ...

### (2) Although :

When using Mathematical logic , "Conjunction" is almost always "AND" , while the English Language (& other Natural Languages) will have **Conventional Customary Alternatives** like :

> but , yet , although , though , furthermore ...

There are more alternatives on Page 94 https://courses.umass.edu/phil110-gmh/text/c04.pdf , & there are other online articles listing the alternatives.

**Mathematical logic will consider these alternatives all Equivalent to AND.**
Humans will treat them a little Differently , due to Emotional Content & nuance in meaning , which is not necessary in Mathematical logic.
These alternatives are used when we want convey contrast & surprise in general.

The Authors might be using "Although" here to high-light that it has no additional meaning in Mathematical logic.
The readers should realize that it will not matter & there will be no change in the logical formulation.

These alternatives are also used when we want **Proof By Contradiction** like this :

> We assumed $X$ & then showed that $Y \implies Z$ , now , we showed that $Z$ is not true **Although** $Y$ is true.
> Hence $X$ must not be true.